# C++ Interface Throwing Unresolved External Symbol Error

Tags: c++, interface, lnk2001

Alright, I've got what should be an easy question but there are literally no examples of what I am looking for online, only copies of the same example which does everything in one file. I'm trying to make an interface and a method to use it like the example below, but I am getting unresolved external symbol errors from visual studio when I compile. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

IFoo.h

```
class IFoo {
public:
    virutal int Bar();
}
```

Foo.h

```
class Foo : public IFoo {
    virtual int Bar();
}
```

Foo.cpp

```
int Foo::Bar() {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: -1 for "virutal" - Post actual code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is the code. I'm looking for an example of how to do this properly because this example throws errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IFoo.h, the virtual method must be pure virtual:

```
class IFoo {
public:
    virtual int Bar() = 0;
};
```

Alternately, provide an default implementation, either inline or in an IFoo.cpp. However, that would make the I prefix misleading, as it wouldn't act like an interface, then.

Comment: damn, I was just missing the "= 0" I didn't realize that was required for this to work. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the unresolved symbol is for `int IFoo::Bar()`, please note that this function is declared to be a callable function and it can, indeed, be called, e.g. using

```
p->IFoo::Bar()
```

That is, you either need to define this function or you need to declare it as not existing:

```
virtual int Bar() = 0;
```

(which still allows you to define it, though).